# How to create custom typeguard that checks whether a value is instance of a given class or not?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to implement a custom typeguard function which checks whether a given value is instance of given class or not.

I tried implementing the same in the following way:

```
function isObject<T>(value: any, className: T = Object as any): value is T {
        return (
            value &&
            typeof value === 'object' &&
            value instanceof (className as any)
        );
}

let myObj:Foo;
if(isObject(fooObj, Foo)) {
    myObj = fooObj;
}
```

But the above-given code throws an error:
`Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is since you pass `Foo` as the second parameter `T` will end up representing the class not an instance of the class. You can extract the instance using the `InstanceType` conditional type:

```
class Foo { private x: null}
function isObject<T extends new (...a: any[])=> any>(value: any, className: T = Object as any): value is InstanceType<T> {
        return (
            value &&
            typeof value === 'object' &&
            value instanceof (className as any)
        );
}
let fooObj: unknown;
let myObj:Foo;
if(isObject(fooObj, Foo)) {
    myObj = fooObj;
}
```

**Note** `istanceof` will act as a type-guard itself.